# Close Popup containing Iframe on click of button from Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm Creating a Iframe dynamically on click of button using Javascript and displaying it in popup. 
In the Iframe I'm loading another website(different domain) which consists of sequence of forms which takes user from first step to last step.
When the user is in last step he would be given a close button within the Iframe. 
I want to close(hide) the popup containing Iframe on click of close button.
Is it Possible?Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of surfing the Web for finding solution I came across this soultion.
The Problem here is that the same-origin policy blocks scripts from accessing contents of site with other origin.
Actually origin consists of the following parts.

```
origin:<protocol(http/https)>://<hostname>:<port number>/path/to/page.html
```

The origin is considered to be different if **protocol**,**hostname** and **port number** are not same.In such cases you can not access the contents of one website from other website due to **same-origin security** policy.

In order to overcome it you have to use **parent-child communication** using **window.postMessage()**.
FYI : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage.
The **Window.postMessage()** method safely enables cross-origin communication.
Suppose that your parent website is **example-parent.com** and In Iframe your loading website **example-iframe.com** and let both are using **http** protocol.
Below is how I solved the problem.
In parent website add event listener for messages to receive as follows.

```
window.addEventListener('message',receiveMessage,false);

function receiveMessage(event){
    var origin = event.origin || event.originalEvent.origin;
    if(origin.indexOf('http://example-iframe.com')>=0) // check if message received from intended sender
    {
        if(event.data=="intended message format") // check if data received is in correct format
        {
            // call functionality that closes popup containing iframe
        }else{ // data received is malacious
            return;
        }

    }else{  // message is not received from intended sender
        return;
    }
}
```

From Iframe post message to the parent website as follows.
Post message syntax : `otherWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer]);`

```
function sendMessage(){
  parent.postMessage('intended message format','http://example-parent.com');
}
```

Use **postMessage()** properly,otherwise it may lead to cross-site scripting attack.

Comment: Also, it is advised to check for rate of received message if your event listener is causing some network calls, this is to prevent DOS attack.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I spent one whole day and this worked so well.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood correctly you want to call a function from child (close button in iframe) which closes the iframe. You can do this by call the parent

```
parent.myfunction() //call myfunction from parent
```

And in parent code you have to implement closing logic

```
   myfunction() {
     iframe.hide() //or whatever
   }
```

Comment: It will work only if origin of parent website and the one loaded in Iframe is Same.

Comment: yes, put document.domain = 'same.domain' in both websites